# extract string using ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as

```
"The Fashion Project - The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute"
```

I need to extract the strings as project name and its description so that it returns an array . So the output should be

```
array[0] = "The Fashion Project"
array[1] = "The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute"
```

I tried it with split method but  the array[1] returned "The Project of Fashion"
I tried it as

```
"The Fashion Project - The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute".split('-')
```

Comment: I presume you always want to split on the first hyphen. If not, it's not well-defined (e.g., The Up-Tempo Project - The Project...) unless spacing around the hyphen is also relevant.

Comment: Have you tried `str.split(/\s+-\s+/)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this also

```
2.1.2 :007 > s = "The Fashion Project - The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute"
 => "The Fashion Project - The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute" 
2.1.2 :008 > s.split(/\s[-\b]\s/)
 => ["The Fashion Project", "The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute"] 
2.1.2 :009 >
```

Comment: `\b` does not do what you think inside of a character class.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below sub command to remove the part including first `-` symbol,

```
"The Test Project - The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute".sub(/^[^-]*- */,"")
=> "The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute"
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[^-]*` Matches any character but not of `-` zero or more times.
- `-` Matches `-`
- `<space>*` Matches zero or more spaces.

**Update:**

```
> "The Test Project - The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute".split(/\s-\s/)
=> ["The Test Project", "The Project of Fashion-Technology and Science-institute"]
```

Comment: Well Explanation... 1+ for this